# iAd banner content Size .. (iAd Support with iOs 4.2 for iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, iad

We have an application that support iAds. Apparently iOs 4.2 for iPad will support this, but
doing some tests with the beta SDK, there is no way to resize de banner to make it fit on the DetailView of a SplitViewController.

in Iphone you set the required content size identifiers for an ad banner, which are ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 or ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32 (refering to Portrait and landscape), but there is no such identifiers in the new sdk for the ipad.

And setting the frame's or bound's width seems to be ignored. In landscape mode the banner size is (1024, 66) and landscape mode is (768, 66) no matter what.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: NDA !!! ask this kind of question on the apple forum developer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I answer this question, I have to remind you that 4.2 beta is under NDA.

I can say that if you look at the API diffs for 4.2 under iAd.framework, you'll see that ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32 has been deprecated and replaced.

Regardless of the device, ads will be the width of the screen. There is no way around this.

Apple's view on iAds is that they should cover either the top or bottom 10% of the screen. Period. In simpler terms, you cannot specify the size of a banner view.

Comment: Thanks! .. so there is no way to workaround this.. related to the identifiers, do you mean that this : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32

Comment: (sorry, just hit the return key and it post the answer)Thanks! .. so there is no way to workaround this.. related to the identifiers, do you mean that this : ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32 is replaced with ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape?

Comment: No, there is no workaround. Even if you managed to change the frame, your app would be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 6 `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifiers` are deprecated, instead use something like this, as per iOS Docs...

```
CGSize adSize = [bannerView sizeThatFits:self.view.frame.size];
```