# What's the height if iAd banner on iPad since OS4.2?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, iad

What is the height of the iAd banner:

```
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait
ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape
```

on an iPad iOS4.2? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832101/iad-banner-content-size-iad-support-with-ios-4-2-for-ipad

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The exact size of advertisements depends on the device the banner is being shown on.

On an iPhone, a *portrait* advertisement is **320 x 50 points** and **480 x 32 points** for a *landscape* advertisement.

On an iPad, a *portrait* advertisement is **768 x 66 points** and **1024 x 66 points** for a *landscape* advertisement.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW8)

Answer (score 2):

The height of the iAd banner is as follow:

ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 &

ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32